# Rust bindgen and systems/compilers where char is wider than 8 bits

Tags: rust, ffi, rust-bindgen

I have a C header file which contains string constants

```c
#define SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_USERNAME "SESSION_USERNAME"
```

and bindgen translates them to

```rust
pub const SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_USERNAME: &'static [u8; 17usize] = b"SESSION_USERNAME\0";
```

(1) How will bindgen behave when C `char` is wider that 8 bits. Will it generate `u16` array?

(2) If so how to consume the translated constants so my Rust code works both on systems
where char is 8 bits and 16 bits. Currently I use `std::ffi::CStr::from_bytes_with_nul()` followed by `.as_ptr()` to convert these constants to `*const c_char` but that won't work because `from_bytes_with_nul` expects `u8` slice.

Comment: IIRC, Rust only supports platforms where `CHAR_BIT` is 8.

Comment: What 16-bit-`char` system are you trying to run on?

Answer (score 1):

https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/layout/scalars.html#char states: (emphasis added)

> Note: Rust `char` type is not layout compatible with C / C++ `char` types. **The C / C++ `char` types correspond to either Rust's `i8` or `u8` types on all currently supported platforms, depending on their signedness. *Rust does not support C platforms in which C `char` is not 8-bit wide.***